# looking to sync or backup outlook "quick steps"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, sync, export

we use a lot of default "quick steps" in outlook, to categorize mails, move to folder, set a flag ecc...
the problem is that exchange do not syncronize those actions, so everytime we have a clean install of outlook we have to set them manually.

is there a way to export or backup those ? or just sync via LAN to others computers.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The quick steps are stored into a hidden folder of your pst / ost. MS Outlook's Export feature does not allow you to export that folder.

So you'll need a third party tool to do it for you.
You can try [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) (I never tried it, always recreated the quick steps manually).

More information can be found [here](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/backup-and-restore-quick-steps).

NB. If you're using Exchange the quick steps should be synced on the server. Maybe you have somthing wrong with the Exchange server.

Comment: Per comment from new user Randy Knight, MFCMAPI is now available here: https://github.com/microsoft/mfcmapi/releases since CodePlex was shut down.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY figured it out, how to backup and restore Quick Steps if you are using IMAP!!!!

There have been SO many posts asking this same question "How do I Export Quick Steps Outlook 365 with IMAP Account using MFCMAPI" and NO one has been able to answer it.

After 5 years of trying to figure this answer out and getting SO frustrated when the only answers were pointing to this post or similar posts with the same instructions: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/backup-and-restore-quick-steps ;

The issue is, ALL the guides for using MFCMAPI don't work if you are using an IMAP account.

I finally got so tired of recreating my Quick Steps (about 30) I started playing around with MFCMAPI again.

The issue with the other guides was they were pointing to the WRONG directory if you used an IMAP account.

I have put together a guide for IMAP users : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/eureka-i-figured-it-out-export-quick-steps-outlook/cee247f8-5898-47a9-a6de-939ebda95139

Answer (score 0):

The current, and official, method of downloading MFCMAPI is located at [Microsoft MFCMAPI Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/mfcmapi/releases)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1239517)

Comment: I have placed this link as a comment under Mik's answer, where it belongs.